# Trojan name I can't find any information about

Tags: virus

I decided to take an online virus scan using ESET online scanner, after getting some weird crash that made my drivers and other parts of the operating system unusable...

The preliminary results say "PHP/Small.NAL trojan", but I cannot find any real information about what it actually is.

What is NAL? What kind of trojan is it? Is it very bad?

Answer (score 1):

The usual naming of malware is [targeted platform]/[name].[variant]

The variants of a malware are numbered alphabetically. When your AV software vendor already uses three letters to describe the variants it means that there are **a lot** of different variants of this particular malware in the wild.

You might find more useful information about this malware when you just search for the family `PHP/Small`.

However, the prefix `PHP` hints that it targets PHP, a server-sided web development language. When you don't have a webserver installed on your machine, it is likely a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/virus-and-malware-information/info/php-small/) you will find a brief description made by AVG Labs.

In [this link](https://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/anatomy-of-a-php-trojan/) you will read an analysis that someone made about another variant of the same trojan.

In [this blog](http://www.whitefirdesign.com/blog/2014/07/07/hackers-hiding-malicious-code-in-exif-data-of-images/), a company lists other names of the same malware given by different security firms.

And [here](http://www.yac.mx/en/guides/trojan-horse-guides/20131030-how-to-remove-PHP/Small.NAW-through-yac-virus-removal-tool.html) you have instructions about manual removing of the NAW variant of the same trojan.